# Ubuntu 12.04LTS fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have installed 12.04LTS on an old Aspire 5520 with the latest BIOS
All goes well, the propriety GPU driver works and I get all the updates.
as soon as I install the proprietary broadcom sta driver for wireless card, and restart the machine I get he fatal "fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed "
this persists after multiple reboots.
It has to be the driver causing this since it was working fine beforehand.
the problem I have is how to fix this without re-installing the whole system again?
I cannot perform the acpi=off since I cannot start a term as I cannot get into Desktop.
and what Broadcom Wireless driver should I use since the one suggested by Ubuntu causes this fault..
any suggestions would be greatly received!
thanks
Pete

Comment: I have the exact same issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/775950 People have suggested editing grub by typing 'e' when it appears and adding: acpi=off nomodeset xforcevesa noapic Between "ro" and "splash". It worked for some but didn't work for me. Feel free to write a new bug report. I think it's only possible through the command line. RB

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, as I encountered this with my Inspiron 1501 recently- boot from the installation media and run Ubuntu live, then use nano, gedit or any other text editor to add the line as needed. You should be able to access the filesystem on the HDD to do so AFAIK.